# Unit Test Spring ApplicationEventPublisher

Tags: spring, junit

I am trying to write a unit test for the following code:

```
public void doSomething(List<Object> someObjects){
    // Some logic I want to test...

    eventPublisher.publishEvent(someEvent);
}
```

So in the project I call this method that perform some logic to the list of objects, and then as a result it publish the Application event with the result  a method that was recieved.

I want to verify the logic inside that method with unit test but I am not sure how I can write the unit test if the method does not return nothing directly but publish a domain event. What is the correct way to do this?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

As part of unit test, it is enough to verify if the `eventPublisher.  is called with the correct argument. And also, remember that unit test is the document for the each every line of code for the method  to be tested.

You have to mock the `eventPublisher` in test and use `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the argument which is being passed while invoking the message.

Ideally, your test should look like:

```
public class ClassToBeTestedTest {

    @Mock
    private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    @InjectMocks
    private ClassToBeTested classToBeTested;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<SomeClass> captor;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSend() throws Exception {

        classToBeTested.doSomething(Arrays.asList());

        verify(eventPublisher).publishEvent(captor.capture());
        assertThat(captor.getValue(), is("expected value"))
    }

}
```